# How to create two arrays in the same loop with CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript, push

I want to create two arrays b and c at the same time. I know two methods which can be able to achieve it. The first method is

```
b = ([i, i * 2] for i in [0..10])
c = ([i, i * 3] for i in [0..10])

alert "b=#{b}"
alert "c=#{c}"
```

This method is very handy for creating only one array. I can not be the better way to get the better performance for computation.

The second method is

```
b = []
c = []
for i in [0..10]
  b.push [i, i*2]
  c.push [i, i*3]

alert "b=#{b}"
alert "c=#{c}"
```

This method seems good for computation efficiency but two lines
    b = []
    c = []
have to be written first. I don't want to write this 2 lines but I have not find a good idea to have the answer. Without the initialization for the arrays of b and c, we can not use push method.

There exists the existential operator ? in Coffeescript but I don't know hot to use it in this problem. Do you have a better method for creating the arrays of b and c without the explicit initialization?

Thank you!

Comment: maybe `b = c = []` will be more suitable?

Comment: Thanks. You will get the same result for b and c. The answer is wrong.

Comment: @varnie: No, the arrays need to be separate, and their contents are different.

Comment: How about [b, c] = [[],[]];

Comment: `[b,c] =[[],[]]` works but is still trapped in the many parens.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a little help from `underscore` (or any other lib that provides `zip`-like functionality):

```
[b, c] = _.zip ([[i, i * 2], [i, i * 3]] for i in [0..10])...
```

After executing it we have:

```
coffee> b 
[ [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 2 ],
  [ 2, 4 ],
  [ 3, 6 ],
  [ 4, 8 ],
  [ 5, 10 ],
  [ 6, 12 ],
  [ 7, 14 ],
  [ 8, 16 ],
  [ 9, 18 ],
  [ 10, 20 ] ]

coffee> c
[ [ 0, 0 ],
  [ 1, 3 ],
  [ 2, 6 ],
  [ 3, 9 ],
  [ 4, 12 ],
  [ 5, 15 ],
  [ 6, 18 ],
  [ 7, 21 ],
  [ 8, 24 ],
  [ 9, 27 ],
  [ 10, 30 ] ]
```

See the [section about splats](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) in CoffeeScript docs for more details and examples.

Comment: Very interesting but it is really a challenge. I haven't got the right answer with it. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the result I get. is it incorrect?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have also got the same results. I forgot the three dots at the end of line. I have not really well understand the usage of the three dots. Thank you very much.

Comment: From CoffeeScript docs: "The JavaScript arguments object is a useful way to work with functions that accept variable numbers of arguments. CoffeeScript provides splats ..., both for function definition as well as invocation, making variable numbers of arguments a little bit more palatable". See the [docs](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) for details and examples.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your kind suggestion. It seems that the splats must be used as an argument of function such as _.zip. I will try to practice more with it.

Answer (score 1):

How about this using the existential operator:

```
for i in [0..10]
    b = [] if not b?.push [i, i*2]
    c = [] if not c?.push [i, i*3]

console.log "b=#{b}"
console.log "c=#{c}"
```

Or to be a bit more understandable:

```
for i in [0..10]
    (if b? then b else b = []).push [i, i*2]
    (if c? then c else c = []).push [i, i*3]

console.log "b=#{b}"
console.log "c=#{c}"
```

**EDIT: from comments:**

> OK but you you have to write so many tedious codes. The same reason is
>   also for ` (b = b or []).push [i, i*2]

It is tedious, so we can wrap it in a function (but beware the variables will be global now):

```
# for node.js
array = (name) -> global[name] = global[name] or []

# for the browser
array = (name) -> window[name] = window[name] or []

for i in [0..10]
    array('b').push [i, i*2]
    array('c').push [i, i*3]

console.log "b=#{b}"
console.log "c=#{c}"
```

Comment: OK but you you have to write so many tedious codes. The same reason is also for  ` (b = b or []).push [i, i*2] `

Comment: Too complex. Still no better way than initializing them separately with `b =[]` and `c = []`. I wonder if there are some ways which can combine the 1st and 2nd methods as I mentioned. We perhaps may need to modify the definition for the push method for the array to make it have a  initial value.

Comment: I agree that the explicit definition is definitely the simplest, and will be the easiest to understand. I wouldn't want to get into extending the .push functionality, seems even messier.

Comment: So do I. Thanks a lot for your kindness suggestion.